# htaccess mod_rewrite change the end of url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made a mistake in a product feed and it will take a few days to fix.

my urls in the feed are:

```
http://www.example.com/productutm_source=ebay_merchant/
```

i need them to be:

```
http://www.example.com/product?utm_source=ebay_merchant/ (notice the question mark)
```

can a rewrite rule in .htaccess fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)(utm_source=ebay_merchant/)$ /$1?$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I forgot to mention 'product' is different for each product is it the utm_source=ebay_merchant/ part that i need to rewrite to ?utm_source=ebay_merchant/

Comment: its working but the redirected url looks like:  /?utm_source%253debay_merchant%252f

Comment: oh ok let me test locally.